# Como validar campos obligatorios en Crear y Opcionales al Editar con Jquery Validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

tratando de realizar la validacion de unos campos que son obligatorios al crear un registro, pero al editarlos estos pueden ser opcionales. por ejemplo el password. cuando lo edito el validador me indica que debo capturarlos. a pesar de que estos pueden cambiarse durante la edicion o no. de igual manera si estos fueran opcionales y al capturarlos me valide la expresion regular en este caso en el password.
alguna idea?

Mensiono que estoy trabajando con un solo modal para crear y editar.

este es el codigo que manejo.

```
 $("#frmUsuarios").validate({
                 
                 rules: {
                     uNombre: "required",
                     uPrimerApellido: "required",
                     uEmail: "required",                
                     uPassword,
                     ucPassword,
                     uPassword: {
                         minlength: 5,
                         regex: /^(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).*$/,
                         required: true,
                     },
                     ucPassword: {
                         minlength: 5,
                         equalTo: "#uPassword",
                         required: true,
                     },
                     uNombre: {
                         regex: /^[^\s]\d*[a-z]*[A-Z]*(?!.*\s{2}).*$/,
                         required: true,
                     },
                     uPrimerApellido: {
                         regex: /^[^\s]\d*[a-z]*[A-Z]*(?!.*\s{2}).*$/,
                         required: true,
                     }
                 },
                 messages: {
                     uNombre: "El campo Nombre es obligatorio.",
                     uPrimerApellido: "El campo Primer Apellido es obligatorio.",
                     uEmail: "Ingrese un correo valido.",
                     uPassword: {
                         regex: "La contraseña debe tener al menos un caracter especial y no contener espacios (ej. !#$%^&*)"
                     },
                     uNombre: {
                         regex: "El campo Nombre no debe de contener espacios en blanco."
                     },
                     uPrimerApellido: {
                         regex: "El campo Primer Apellido no debe de contener espacios en blanco."
                     }
                 },
                 success: function (label, element) {
                     // Add the span element, if doesn't exists, and apply the icon classes to it.
                     if (!$(element).next("span")[0]) {
                         //$("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback'></span>").insertAfter($(element));
                     }
                 },
                 highlight: function (element) {
                     $(element).removeClass('is-valid').addClass('is-invalid');
                 },
                 unhighlight: function (element) {
                     $(element).removeClass('is-invalid').addClass('is-valid');
                 },
                 submitHandler: function (form, event) {
                     event.preventDefault();

                     Submited();
                 }
             });
```

Submited() es el metodo ajax. por lo que veo es dinamico la generacion de las reglas. esta regla obviamente funciona al crear pero no de la forma deseada en editar. alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrega un campo oculto con ID de usuario. Suponiendo que es autoincrementable, al crear tendrá valor cero y al editar será mayor que cero:

```
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="5">
```

En tu función:

```
$("#frmUsuarios").validate({
             rules: {
                 uNombre: "required",
                 uPrimerApellido: "required",
                 uEmail: "required",                
                 uPassword,
                 ucPassword,
                 uPassword: {
                     minlength: 5,
                     regex: /^(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).*$/,
                     // Verdadero si es cero, falso si no
                     required: function() {
                        return (parseInt($("#user_id").val() == 0);
                     },
                 },
                 ucPassword: {
                     minlength: 5,
                     equalTo: "#uPassword",
                     required: function() {
                        return (parseInt($("#user_id").val() == 0);
                     },
                 },
                 uNombre: {
                     regex: /^[^\s]\d*[a-z]*[A-Z]*(?!.*\s{2}).*$/,
                     required: true,
                 },
                 uPrimerApellido: {
                     regex: /^[^\s]\d*[a-z]*[A-Z]*(?!.*\s{2}).*$/,
                     required: true,
                 }
             },
             messages: {
                 uNombre: "El campo Nombre es obligatorio.",
                 uPrimerApellido: "El campo Primer Apellido es obligatorio.",
                 uEmail: "Ingrese un correo valido.",
                 uPassword: {
                     regex: "La contraseña debe tener al menos un caracter especial y no contener espacios (ej. !#$%^&*)"
                 },
                 uNombre: {
                     regex: "El campo Nombre no debe de contener espacios en blanco."
                 },
                 uPrimerApellido: {
                     regex: "El campo Primer Apellido no debe de contener espacios en blanco."
                 }
             },
             success: function (label, element) {
                 // Add the span element, if doesn't exists, and apply the icon classes to it.
                 if (!$(element).next("span")[0]) {
                     //$("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback'></span>").insertAfter($(element));
                 }
             },
             highlight: function (element) {
                 $(element).removeClass('is-valid').addClass('is-invalid');
             },
             unhighlight: function (element) {
                 $(element).removeClass('is-invalid').addClass('is-valid');
             },
             submitHandler: function (form, event) {
                 event.preventDefault();

                 Submited();
             }
         });
```

Comment: ya tengo el campo, voy aprobarlo

Comment: no sigue validando los campos

Comment: Cambié la evaluación por una función, prueba ahora. Referencia: [required con condición](https://jqueryvalidation.org/required-method/#example:-makes-%22parent%22-required-only-if-age-is-below-13)

Comment: en hora buena. si, funciono

Comment: Me alegra que haya funcionado, no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada.